# Error in Filezilla connection

Tags: filezilla

When i connect with my server using filezilla at that time FTP shows me this error :

```
550 Can't change directory to ..: Permission denied
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Response:   421 Timeout - try typing a little faster next time
Error:  GnuTLS error -110 in gnutls_record_recv: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Status: Server did not properly shut down TLS connection
Error:  Could not read from socket: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Disconnected from server
```

Can anyone tell me about this error?

Comment: You are trying to login to the `..` directory. Probably this is atop of your root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once i got same error like this.
This seems like you have a problem with the server provider.

so don't do anything just directly call to Server provider and tell them your issue about filezilla.

They will shortout in couple of hours or may be in days.

Comment: Thanks i'll do it soon.